# Excel - Can't tick boxes in the Select Data Source dialog

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have been trying to record a macro that would select a specific series to display on a graph.

Since I can't use my mouse and I do not know VBA, I have been trying to record this using only my keyboard. However, when I reach the "Select Data" menu (Chart Tools > Design > Select Data), the space bar does not check any box. It does check other options in other menus perfectly well.

Is there a way to check series in the "Select Data" menu using only my keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the checkbox before you can use the space bar to check or uncheck it.

When you first open the Select Data Source dialog, the "Chart data range" textbox has the focus. Use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key repeatedly until one of the items in the group you want to change is selected. If you are changing the Legend entries, the dialog should look something like this:

[image]

Now use the arrow keys to select the item you want to check. Then hit <kbd>tab</kbd> one more time to move the focus to the checkbox. The dialog will now look something like this:

[image]

You can now use the space bar to check or uncheck the box.